# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (int)

Tags: c#, object, reference, set, instance

This error keeps popping up and I can't seem to figure out where it's coming from.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable LocalCart = new DataTable();
    LocalCart = (DataTable)Session["cart"];
    int LocalCartItemCount = (int) Session["CartItemCount"];
    Decimal LocalCartAmount = (Decimal)Session["CartAmount"];

    if (LocalCart.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        titleLabel.Text = "Your shopping cart is empty!";
        GridCart.Visible = false;
        updateButton.Enabled = false;
        checkoutButton.Enabled = false;
        totalAmountLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        GridCart.DataSource = LocalCart;
        GridCart.DataBind();
        titleLabel.Text = "These are the products in your shopping cart:";
        GridCart.Visible = true;
        updateButton.Enabled = true;
        checkoutButton.Enabled = true;
        totalAmountLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", LocalCartAmount);
    }
```

It's saying the error is here -> `int LocalCartItemCount = (int) Session["CartItemCount"];`

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking to see if the key `"CartItemCount"` exists in Session. If it does not exist, then the result of `Session["CartItemCount"]` will return null and create that error when trying to cast null to an `(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the session object doesn't exist it will return null which will break the cast.  You should look into using int.tryparse.  If successful it will update the integer, if not it won't bomb out.

try the following code

```
int LocalCartItemCount;
int.TryParse(Session["CartItemCount"].ToString(), out LocalCartItemCount);
```

plan b

```
int LocalCartItemCount = (int)(Session["CartItemCount"] ?? 0);
```

Comment: If Session["CartItemCount"] is null, this will give you an object reference error.

Comment: Same error here now -> int.TryParse(Session["CartItemCount"].ToString(), out LocalCartItemCount);

Comment: It works, but the same error popped up at another place now, the line after with CartAmount.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first issue is that `Session["CartItemCount"]` is most likely null. Since you are attempting to use this null value in your cast, you are receiving an object reference error.

This could be corrected with C#'s `??` operator:

```
int LocalCartItemCount = (int)(Session["CartItemCount"] ?? 0);
```

That line is basically shorthand for this:

```
int LocalCartItemCount;
if(Session["CartItemCount"] != null)
    LocalCartItemCount = Session["CartItemCount"];
else
    LocalCartItemCount = 0;
```

That should work, so long as `Session["CartItemCount"]` is always an integer. If it is not an integer, however, you might receive one of the following errors:

- `Specified cast is not valid`
- `Cannot unbox 'Session["CartItemCount"]' as 'int'`

If there is a risk of these errors above, then you may have to expand it to something like this:

```
int LocalCartItemCount = 0;
if (Session["CartItemCount"] != null) 
{
    Int32.TryParse(Session["CartItemCount"].ToString(), out LocalCartItemCount);
}
```

Usually, though, I prefer not to use `TryParse` outside of a boolean expression, but it still can.

Keep in mind that you will need to similar null checks for any of your objects coming in from session. So, for the `LocalCart.Rows.Count == 0` check mentioned in the comments, for example, I would change the `if` to read:

```
if(LocalCart != null && LocalCart.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `??` operator as described above.

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried it and it worked for the CartItemCount.  It didnt work for the CartAmount so I tried your second solution and it worked.  But now I have another problem but same error, this time with  -> if (LocalCart.Rows.Count == 0)

Code:-

Comment: @ArshadÃršhâdJugon if `Session["cart"]` is null, the it will reset your LocalCart DataTable to null. In that case, make your if into this: `if(LocalCart != null && LocalCart.Rows.Count == 0)` Alternatively, you could try this:  `(DataTable)(Session["cart"] ?? new DataTable()`